# Disable pinging slaves in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, plugins, amazon-ec2, system-properties

So, we are seeing tons of our EC2 slaves go offline (using EC2 plugin). So to debug it I am trying to disabe pinging thread based on the article [Pinging thread](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Ping+Thread) where they talk about disabling the ping thread on the master JVM on a running jenkins using:

Jenkins.instance.injector.getInstance(hudson.slaves.ChannelPinger.class).@pingInterval = -1

and to disable slaves from pinging the master, the system property -Dhudson.remoting.Launcher.pingIntervalSec=-1 needs to be set to slaves.

**Questions:**

1. Where and how do I add the pingInterval value to -1?
2. How and where do I set the system property for pingIntervalSec=-1

We are seeing tons of slaves going offline and I want to see if ping interval can help.

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: the answer below seems to resolve your question please mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the master node, you can change the system property under `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins`

```
JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dhudson.remoting.Launcher.pingIntervalSec=-1"
```

you can set the system property when you are running the slave (via JNPL):

```
java -Dhudson.remoting.Launcher.pingIntervalSec=-1 -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl <Jenkins root URL>
```

-K

Comment: I wonder if "Response time" option under "Manage Jenkins" -> "Nodes" -> "Configure" is doing the same?

Answer (score 2):

From Jenkins version 2.37, the names of these properties are slightly different:

- **hudson.slaves.ChannelPinger.pingInterval** - Since: 1.405, Default:
  5, (Deprecated since 2.37) Frequency (in minutes) of pings between the controller and agents
- **hudson.slaves.ChannelPinger.pingIntervalSeconds** - Since: 2.37, Default:
  300, Frequency of pings between the controller and agents, in seconds
- **hudson.slaves.ChannelPinger.pingTimeoutSeconds** - Since: 2.37, Default:
  240, Timeout for each ping between the controller and agents, in seconds

See a list with all "Jenkins Features Controlled with System Properties" (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/system-properties/ )